# How can I detect whether contextIsolation is enabled in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have two separate BrowserWindows in my app, and one of them has contextIsolation off. As a result, trying to use `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld` throws this error:

```
Error: contextBridge API can only be used when contextIsolation is enabled
```

Is it possible to detect whether contextIsolation is disabled from the preload script so I can fall back to setting window properties directly in that case?

Comment: Catch the error when its thrown?

Comment: @Marc lol that would probably work but I found a better solution

Comment: What about not loading a preload script for this window if you know it will not work?

Comment: @Arkellys it's not the preload script as such that doesn't work, it's the specific method of exposing an API from the preload script that needs to be different

Answer (score 0):

`process.contextIsolated` is a boolean provided by the environment that can be used for this purpose.

See https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/process#processcontextisolated-readonly